# Hyperledger REST API roadmap

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

With Hyperledger composer deprecated and fabric-rest-api (https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric-sdk-rest) archived, what is the future roadmap of REST API for Hyperledger fabric? What is recommended way  to expose rest APIs with Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.x? 
The documentation (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/fabric-sdks.html) mentions that REST SDK will be provided in subsequent releases - but cannot find a roadmap.